# Filling multidimensional matrix from file is slow on Windows

Tags: c++, rcpp

I wrote a C++ (Rcpp) function to read and fill a multidimensional matrix from a file containing only numbers. When I run it on Linux it works fine and it is pretty fast. However, the same code is much slower (by a factor of 200) on a Windows machine with the same spec. Anyone can spot the problem?

```cpp
void read_ed0moins_lut_(const char *filename, float downward_irradiance_table_as_output[NBWL][NTHETAS][NO3][NTAUCLD][NALB]) {

    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);
    float tmp;
    for (int theta = 0; theta < NTHETAS; theta++) {
        for (int ozone = 0; ozone < NO3; ozone++) {
            for (int taucl = 0; taucl < NTAUCLD; taucl++) {
                for (int albedo = 0; albedo < NALB; albedo++) {
                    for (int wavelength = 0; wavelength < NBWL; wavelength++) {
                        infile >> tmp; // This line is very slow on Windows
                        downward_irradiance_table_as_output[wavelength][theta][ozone][taucl][albedo] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Close file
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you have optimizations enabled?

Comment: I think I have it with the -02 flag. Is that right?

Comment: What if you use `fscanf()` instead of `ifstream`?

Comment: @PhilippeMassicotte What compiler are you using to produce an executable on windows? MSVC's highest optimization setting is `/O2`, while clang/gcc has `-O3` as highest. Note that MSVC uses a slash, not a minus.

Comment: I am using http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: How large is the file? It might be more efficient to read (at least parts of) the file into memory instead of trying to read it float per float.

Comment: It is about 15 Mb, containing roughly 15 000 numbers.

Comment: @PhilippeMassicotte Given this huge difference of factor 200, I'm sure you've got a caching problem. I'd recommend to read the entire file into a buffer and process the numbers from there. Allocating 15 MB from the heap is nothing to be scared of, nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

1. Build in *Release* mode (with optimization enabled, `-O2` flag)
2. Enable `ifstream` buffering:

```
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    char buffer[65536];
    infile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

3. Arrange your array's dimensions in the order of the loops:

   `downward_irradiance_table_as_output[NTHETAS][NO3][NTAUCLD][NALB][NBWL]`

   so that you get [row-major-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) traversal, which is more cache-friendly.